# How to access tensorflow layer attributes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am new to tensorflow. I have a custom tensorflow model which has a variable in mul layer. I would like to access the variable y shown in the image.

[Model Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzkPO.png)

I tried to print the attributes using **getattribute** but it is throwing error as y is not an attribute. I have printed dir() for the layer object, but not able to find anything to get the variable.

```
savedModel=tf.keras.models.load_model('./tf_model.h5')
k = savedModel.layers
for i in k:
    if i.name == 'tf.math.multiply_25':
        print(dir(i))
```

```
Output: 
['_TF_MODULE_IGNORED_PROPERTIES', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_activity_regularizer', '_add_trackable', '_add_trackable_child', '_add_variable_with_custom_getter', '_already_warned', '_auto_get_config', '_auto_track_sub_layers', '_autocast', '_autographed_call', '_build_input_shape', '_call_spec', '_call_wrapper', '_callable_losses', '_captured_weight_regularizer', '_cast_single_input', '_check_variables', '_checkpoint_dependencies', '_clear_losses', '_compute_dtype', '_compute_dtype_object', '_dedup_weights', '_deferred_dependencies', '_delete_tracking', '_deserialization_dependencies', '_deserialize_from_proto', '_dtype', '_dtype_policy', '_dynamic', '_eager_losses', '_expects_mask_arg', '_expects_training_arg', '_export_to_saved_model_graph', '_flatten', '_flatten_layers', '_flatten_modules', '_functional_construction_call', '_gather_children_attribute', '_gather_saveables_for_checkpoint', '_get_cell_name', '_get_existing_metric', '_get_input_masks', '_get_node_attribute_at_index', '_get_save_spec', '_get_trainable_state', '_get_unnested_name_scope', '_handle_activity_regularization', '_handle_deferred_dependencies', '_handle_weight_regularization', '_inbound_nodes', '_inbound_nodes_value', '_infer_output_signature', '_init_call_fn_args', '_init_set_name', '_initial_weights', '_input_spec', '_instrument_layer_creation', '_instrumented_keras_api', '_instrumented_keras_layer_class', '_instrumented_keras_model_class', '_is_layer', '_keras_api_names', '_keras_api_names_v1', '_keras_tensor_symbolic_call', '_load_own_variables', '_lookup_dependency', '_losses', '_map_resources', '_maybe_build', '_maybe_cast_inputs', '_maybe_create_attribute', '_maybe_initialize_trackable', '_metrics', '_metrics_lock', '_must_restore_from_config', '_name', '_name_based_attribute_restore', '_name_based_restores', '_name_scope', '_name_scope_on_declaration', '_no_dependency', '_non_trainable_weights', '_obj_reference_counts', '_obj_reference_counts_dict', '_object_identifier', '_outbound_nodes', '_outbound_nodes_value', '_preload_simple_restoration', '_preserve_input_structure_in_config', '_restore_from_tensors', '_save_own_variables', '_saved_model_arg_spec', '_saved_model_inputs_spec', '_self_setattr_tracking', '_self_tracked_trackables', '_serialize_to_proto', '_serialize_to_tensors', '_set_connectivity_metadata', '_set_dtype_policy', '_set_mask_keras_history_checked', '_set_mask_metadata', '_set_save_spec', '_set_trainable_state', '_set_training_mode', '_setattr_tracking', '_should_cast_single_input', '_stateful', '_supports_masking', '_tf_api_names', '_tf_api_names_v1', '_thread_local', '_track_trackable', '_track_variable', '_track_variables', '_trackable_children', '_trackable_saved_model_saver', '_tracking_metadata', '_trainable', '_trainable_weights', '_unconditional_checkpoint_dependencies', '_unconditional_dependency_names', '_update_trackables', '_update_uid', '_updates', '_use_input_spec_as_call_signature', '_warn', 'activity_regularizer', 'add_loss', 'add_metric', 'add_update', 'add_variable', 'add_weight', 'build', 'built', 'call', 'compute_dtype', 'compute_mask', 'compute_output_shape', 'compute_output_signature', 'count_params', 'dtype', 'dtype_policy', 'dynamic', 'finalize_state', 'from_config', 'function', 'get_config', 'get_input_at', 'get_input_mask_at', 'get_input_shape_at', 'get_output_at', 'get_output_mask_at', 'get_output_shape_at', 'get_weights', 'inbound_nodes', 'input', 'input_mask', 'input_shape', 'input_spec', 'losses', 'metrics', 'name', 'name_scope', 'non_trainable_variables', 'non_trainable_weights', 'outbound_nodes', 'output', 'output_mask', 'output_shape', 'set_weights', 'stateful', 'submodules', 'supports_masking', 'symbol', 'trainable', 'trainable_variables', 'trainable_weights', 'updates', 'variable_dtype', 'variables', 'weights', 'with_name_scope']
```

Can anybody guide me how to access it ?
I am using python - 3.9, tensorflow - 2.10

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `dir()` is not the correct method to access it. Have you tried `k.weights`?

Comment: If you want the weights you can access them with `[i for i in savedModel.trainable_weights if i.name == 'tf.math.multiply_25']`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have tried with both weights and trainable_weights but both return an empty list. Actually for my model it is showing the number of parameters as zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pythonic approach as follows:

###### Continuing the code snippet you attached.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

savedModel=tf.keras.models.load_model('./tf_model.h5')

first_layer = savedModel.layers[0]

for layer in savedModel.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)
```